# How do these nested JavaScript functions work?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a question related to this code:

```
const somaHorasExtras = (salario, valorHorasExtras) => salario + valorHorasExtras;

const calculaDescontos = (salario, descontos) => salario - descontos;

const verifiqueSe = (valor) => {
  const assercoes = {
    ehExatamenteIgualA(esperado) {
      if (valor !== esperado) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-throw-literal
        throw {};
      }
    },
  };
  return assercoes;
};

const teste = (titulo, funcaoDeTeste) => {
  try {
    funcaoDeTeste();
    console.log(`${titulo} passou!`);
  } catch {
    console.error(`${titulo} não passou!!!`);
  }
};

teste('somaHorasExtras', () => {
  const esperado = 2500;
  const retornado = somaHorasExtras(2000, 500);

  verifiqueSe(retornado).ehExatamenteIgualA(esperado);
});

teste('calculaDesconto', () => {
  const esperado = 2300;
  const retornado = calculaDescontos(2500, 200);

  verifiqueSe(retornado).ehExatamenteIgualA(esperado);
});
```

My question is related to the verifiqueSe function specifically. How does this function work? Does someone can explain how this function work in conjunction with the inner function ehExatamenteIgualA? What is the assercoes which is returned?

Thank you.

Comment: where is ehExatamenteIgualA declared?

Comment: obviously it is in a higher scope.

Comment: `assercoes` is an object with a function `ehExatamenteIgualA`

Comment: `ehExatementeIgualA` isn't really an innter function. It's just a member on the `assercoes` object. That object gets constructed and returned. There's no real interaction between the two except that when you invoke `ehEWxatementeIgualA` it will have closed over the `valor` value passed to `verifiqueSe` when it was created.

Comment: @FelipeEsteves it's declared on line 7. The `{ functionName(args) {...} }` syntax is shorthand for `{functionName: function functionName(args) {...}}`

Comment: that's all the code that I have inside a file named index.js. I'm running it using node index.js. I think this answers the question where the ehExatamenteIgualA function is declared.

Answer (score 2):

Your `verifiqueSe(valor)` function returns an object. You may find it a little confusing, since this syntax:

```js
const foo = {
    bar() {
        //
    }
};
```

is just a short syntax for object method:

```js
const foo = {
    bar: function () {
        //
    }
};
```

So in order to call the `bar()` function, you'd need to reach it through `foo`:

```js
foo.bar();
```